# Какое склонение выбрать: "фокусирует зрение Горацио на короле/короля"

Tags: склонение

Гамлет фокусирует зрение Горацио на короля.

Правильно будет "на короля" или "на короле"?

Вроде бы правильно "на короле". Но смысл тот, что один направляет зрение на другого на короля. Я запуталась...

Comment: Думаю, здесь не направляет зрение, а сосредотачивает на короле.

Answer (score 2):

Верно: **Фокусировать на чем-л., ком-л.** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

По-моему, даже в переносном смысле нельзя говорить "фокусировать на что-либо, кого-либо".

Вообще, фраза кажется мне неудачной. В Нацкорпусе мне не удалось найти ни одного примера с фокусировкой зрения. Фокусируют взгляд или внимание. Именно **вниманием** Горацио управляет Гамлет. В качестве алтернативы можно ли сказать: "Гамлет направляет взгляд Горацио на короля"? Формально верно, но по сути не очень. Воображение рисует Гамлета, поворачивающего голову Горацио в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 1):

[Толковый словарь Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/258362/%D0%A4%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%98%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC):

ФОКУСИ́РОВАТЬ
3. *перен.* Сосредоточивать, ставить в центр чего-нибудь (*книжн*.).
Фокусировать внимание, мысль на чём-нибудь.

Получается: **фокусирует** (что?) **зрение** (на ком?) ***на короле.***

[Обычно так не говорят, потому что "фокусирование (рас/фокусировка) зрения" — это медицинский термин (*аккомодация* — процесс фокусировки глаза на предметах, расположенных на различных расстояниях).]

Мне кажется, что лучше сказать так: обращает (или направляет, или концентрирует, или сосредотачивает) внимание (взгляд, интерес).

Answer (score 0):

**Гамлет фокусирует зрение Горацио на короля.**

Я бы оставила этот вариант, так как здесь глагол "фокусировать" имеет скорее **переносное значение**: Гамлет **направляет** зрение (внимание) Горацио на короля, а это В.п.

В других же случаях обычно используется П.п.: фокусировать взгляд или внимание на каком-либо предмете.

**Из словаря:**

ФОКУСИРОВАТЬ,  3. Сосредоточивать, ставить в центр чего-л. Ф. внимание, мысль **на этих проблемах.**

**Примеры:**

Она мгновенно **фокусирует на себе внимание**, стоит ей лишь появиться на экране или на сцене. [Актриса Вера Сотникова: «Мой дом  — мое удовольствие!» (2004) // «Мир & Дом. City», 2004.01.15]

Тема медицины: В этом случае человек **не может сфокусировать взгляд** на предмете или объекте.